# PInvoke marshalling const char * fails with UnmanagedType.LPStr

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm failing to understand why the .NET Core marshalling is failing to work with the one marshakking approach but not another. In the example below `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` can successfully marshal a string from the native dll but the same call with the `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` attribute cannot? Or is the marshalling from the IntPtr just getting lucky and could also access invalid memory depending on the OS memory management?

The C library code is (compiled as C not C++):

```c
static const char str[] = "Hello World";

__declspec(dllexport) const char* getstr() {
  return str;
}
```

C# test program:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CLibraryPinvoke
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string LIB_NAME = "CLibrary";

        [DllImport(LIB_NAME, EntryPoint = "getstr")]
        public static extern IntPtr getstrgood();

        [DllImport(LIB_NAME, EntryPoint ="getstr")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static extern string getstrbad();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"getstr={Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(getstrgood())}.");

            // Crash.
            Console.WriteLine($"getstr={getstrbad()}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Execution result:

```
getstr=Hello World.
CLibraryPinvoke\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CLibraryPinvoke.exe (process 31848) exited with code -1073740940.
```

Comment: `PtrToStringAnsi` copies the string from the buffer. `UnmanagedType.LPStr` copies the string from the buffer and releases it [with `CoTaskMemFree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#unmanaged-signature). Releasing a `static const char[]` with `CoTaskMemFree` crashes the program.

Comment: @GSerg - you should answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PtrToStringAnsi` copies the string from the buffer pointed to by the return value.

`UnmanagedType.LPStr` copies the string from the buffer pointed to by the return value, and releases it [with `CoTaskMemFree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#unmanaged-signature). Releasing a `static const char[]` with `CoTaskMemFree` crashes the program.

This is because the semantic of the return value is that the memory that holds the result was allocated on the called side.

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#unmanaged-signature), if the memory is allocated on the called side, but should not be released with `CoTaskMemFree`, you must marshal it as `IntPtr` and release it yourself using the appropriate method.
The appropriate method for memory backed up by a `static const char[]` is to leave it alone.

This requires the user of your function to have knowledge of implementation details of your function, which is not a good thing. Of course, you can document the function as returning memory that should never be released, but then it would probably not be a very useful function, and if you were to change its behaviour in the future, you would be stuck with returning one of the possible `static const char[]`s.
You can avoid all that by allocating the memory each time and letting the .NET runtime to manage the rest, or by making the function accept a `char*` argument to copy the response into.